# Is Docker highly sensitive to the kernel, the host and the filesystem it’s using?

Tags: docker

Disclaimer: I'm a newbie trying to learn more about Docker and its utility in developing and deploying Python applications. In my research, I found a widely circulated [blog post](https://thehftguy.com/2017/02/23/docker-in-production-an-update/) that states:

> As you should be aware by know, Docker is highly sensitive to the
>   kernel, the host and the filesystem it’s using. Pick the wrong
>   combination and you’re talking kernel panic, filesystem corruption,
>   Docker daemon lock down, etc…

Is this assessment accurate? If so, what can one do to guard against these types of incompatibility failures?

Comment: Use trusted Docker repositories and installation scripts for your OS

Comment: This is probably going to get closed as opinionated. For the record, have been at multiple companies running massive Docker based infrastructure and have relationships with people at a bunch more, and would not consider any of the claims made in the blog post to be accurate. Under typical workloads, it is unlikely that Docker will be the most unreliable part of your system, IMO.

Comment: @PaulBecotte I'd be surprised if massive infrastructures weren't super-careful when choosing their OS, kernel, filesystems etc. However, isn't the purpose of containerization to remove these dependencies?

Comment: If you're using Docker for normal workloads and aren't pushing against the edges of how things work (like using the copy-on-write file system for important work like this guys seems to have?) you are going to be okay. If you need to push the edges, then you need to be thoughtful about every level of your infrastructure, and not using docker isn't going to make it any easier. Either way, I don't agree with anything in the blog post.

Comment: That blog post smells like someone had a bad experience and an axe to grind. Spend some time working with Docker yourself and form your own opinions. Certainly there are many people using it both for for development and production service deployment.

Comment: @larsks Is there anything wrong with blogging about your (negative) experiences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this compatibility matrix

https://success.docker.com/article/Compatibility_Matrix

Using other host OS versions is not supported, and in some cases can, in fact, trigger kernel panics, for example: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29397 (although a kernel panic presumably suggests a bug in the kernel rather than the application)